# D3js draws only one feature within geoJSON FeatureCollection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

although being pretty new to D3js I already get most of the things up and running. However, what is not yet working, is the display of a geoJSON-based map of inner-city boundaries (data: http://ddj.haim.it/data/muenchen.geojson).

Here's what I have been trying lately:

```
var nWidth = 800, nHeight = 600,
    oMap = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', nWidth).attr('height', nHeight),
    oProjection = d3.geo.mercator().center([ 11.591, 48.139 ]).scale(50000).translate([nWidth / 2, nHeight / 2]),
    oPath = d3.geo.path().projection(oProjection);
d3.json('data/muenchen.geojson', function(_mError, _oCollection) {
    oMap.append('g')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(_oCollection.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'entity')
        .attr('d', oPath);
});
```

What do I get? A map where only the last featue is drawn correctly and another one is drawn as one huge rectangle (well, in the source, it's not a rect, it's a path).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch,
Mario

Comment: Make sure that you're not filling the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I get your point, Lars. I can see the last polygon from the geoJSON, however, only the last one. Here's the current output: http://ddj.haim.it/d3.html

EDIT: Okay, I got your point. Sorry and thanks a lot for the answer.
The key thing is to "fill" the paths (in the CSS) with transparency.